# Online WSDL parser and test code generator

Tags: wsdl

Is it possible to generate code coverage of WSDL file online ?

Answer (score 1):

I have an tool that will do basic code coverage generation - [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer).

Check the Generate Test Classes option before pressing Generate Apex Classes.

[image: Generate Code Coverage for Wsdl2Apex output]

It currently needs to be run on a Windows machine or compatible environment. <strike>Unfortunately there isn't an online version of it yet.</strike> There is now a basic online version as well that will take your WSDL and generate basic code coverage for you.

The code coverage it generates won't check semantics, it is purely concerned with line coverage. If you want to do meaningful tests that understand real world expected inputs and outputs you will need to code those by hand.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool available that can write test code coverage for your WSDL generated code. You will have to write it by yourself.